# OllyDbg and XMM0 vs MM0 registers

Tags: ollydbg

How can I view the `XMM0`-`XMM7` registers within OllyDbg? I can right click on the registers window and go to `view MMX` registers, but I'm not exactly sure that these are the same. I see an instruction: `MOVSS DWORD PTR DS:[ESI+8],XMM0` and as step through that instruction, the value shown in `MM0` on the register window does not become the value stored at `[ESI+8]`.

So, I suppose another question is: *Are the `XMM0` and `MM0` registers different?*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer properly your question, yes. `xmm` registers were introduced by Intel with the `SSE` instruction set (IS) in 1999 with the Pentium III CPU. `SSE` stands for Streaming SIMD Extension and is a set of vector instructions. `xmm` registers are 128bit wide and can hold 4 `floats`, 2 `doubles`, or 16 `chars`. `SSE` can speed up signal processing applications (image processing, sound processing, compression, ...), encryption, and others quite dramatically when used properly.

On the other hand, `mm` registers are part of the `MMX` IS, another vector instruction set older than `SSE` (1997 I suppose), and are 64bit wide. 
Nowadays the vector instruction sets are becoming quite a *fashion* in a certain way (vector `CPUs` were the standard for supercomputers back in the 70s & 80s - Cray's, ThinkingMachine's, ... computer were all vector based). In the past few years, Intel came up with many versions of `SSE` and two new IS called `AVX` & `AVX2` (Advanced Vector Extension) with 256bit wide vectors implemented on SandyBridge/IvyBridge/Haswell, and `AVX-512` first implemented on the KNC (Knight's Corner) of the Xeon Phi processor & co-processor line.

I encourage you to check the Intel documentation & Wikipedia for more information.

Answer (score 3):

So it turns out the [SSE Registers (XMM0-7)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Streaming_SIMD_Extensions) are not supported within OllyDbg v1.10, but are in v2.0 which I found, [and downloaded here](http://www.ollydbg.de/version2.html), and works great so far. The newest version does not, however, support plugins.